# Fix CORS issue on react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, cors, react-pdf

I am trying to fetch pdf from s3 links and display in the react app. I am using react-pdf for it. but when react-pdf makes api call to fetch the pdf I am getting this error

Access to fetch at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

on React app I have also added this,

source={{
header: {
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
},
}}

Comment: Is the backend allowing cross-domain request?

Comment: Seems like you need to understand what CORS is a bit better. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs set on the server (s3), not the client (react app).  This is a good write up, be sure to notice the difference between request and response. For example, the 'preflight' is a common point of confusion. https://auth0.com/blog/cors-tutorial-a-guide-to-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 8):

This message tell us that back-end not allow to your client side make `HTTP` request.

So you have to config your fetch to make a `CORS` request, but I couldn't find any way to config `react-pdf` to do it for you, you may have to cache it and then render it...

However to access Amazon S3 Link you have to manage [`Bucket configuration options`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingBucket.html#bucket-config-options-intro) to allow `CORS` fetch requests like this([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html#cors-example-1)):

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://www.example1.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://www.example2.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

For more information [Using cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html) from Amazon S3 user guid.

Comment: What if the url is not created from Amazon S3? I am having issue but there is no any solution, could you please suggest anything else?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda any more detail...? Do you mean that the file is not hosted by S3 but you cannot make `react-pdf` work?

Comment: Yes, I have image file which is loading from my domain itself, API call is working fine but when I want to load an image in react-pdf its showing an error, here is an issue: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/343#issuecomment-1025394344